# Как вывести каждую третью запись из таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Как вывести каждую 3 запись из таблицы в MySQL?Какие операторы использовать для этого

Comment: самое простое по остатку от деления id на 3. но надо что бы id шли подряд. либо перенумеровать записи переменной и по ней так же. Вообще задача странная, интересно зачем это могло понадобиться

Comment: Занимаюсь практикой и интересно стало как это реализовать.Только вот про остаток от деления до этого я не слышал.

Comment: Что такое остаток от деления я знаю, но вот про реализацию на Sql не знал спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Простой способ, но опирающийся на предположение, что id идут подряд:

```
select * from table_name where id % 3 = 1;
```

Посложнее, но не делающий предположений:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS rownum, some_column 
    FROM (SELECT @row := 0) r, table_name
) ranked 
WHERE rownum % 3 = 1
```

Comment: Надо еще учесть, что порядок возврата не гарантирован и добавить ORDER BY ID.